# SQL generated by the entity framework - unable to view in output Window

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6, xdebug, output-window

I know this question is been asked by already been replied over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework). However the problem i'm facing is im unable to view the SQL generated in output window. I'm using EF6 and assume this to be a simple problem. screenshot attached for your reference.

[image]

Am i missing anything?

Thank you

Comment: You're probably running in release mode.

Comment: @Gert : I have replaced the picture in my question. i guess the project is running debugger in debug mode. Please let me know if im heading wrong. Thank you

Comment: Does Debug.WriteLine("Test"); show up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369820/debug-writeline-shows-nothing

Comment: Debug.WriteLine("Test"); didn't show up. However, the answer provided from  @Guillermo your reference link paved the path to resolve the issue. Thank you Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much to do with settings in visual studio Menu > tools > options > debugging > General:

Answer was simple and precise. Got resolved this from the below post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29263113/3234286